# Detach database from User Instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can't seem to figure out how to detach databases from a User Instance in MSSQLEXPRESS?

I have googled it but have not seen a definitive answer anywhere.

Anyone have an info on this?

Comment: Is it you don't  want to give User Permissions to view database Or you wan't to detach The DB From Server

Comment: Thanks for the question: I want to detach the database from the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Right CLick ON Database >> GO TO Task >> Click ON DETACH
```

OR Follow the Step IN Link given Below

https://www.systoolsgroup.com/updates/attach-detach-sql-server-database/

Comment: That only works for my "main server". Not that this is a USER INSTANCE, and I dont see that instance in Management Studio, dont even know if it can be connected to using Managment Studio?

Comment: check the User Permission.Permission might be mission for the user.  It can Be Done Through User Instance Also as I'm regular on this

Comment: Changed permissions to what seemed logical, still cant see the User Instance.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "user instance"? Which instance is "user" instance and which "not user"? Are you trying to detach databases from instance to which you cannot even connect?